# Async/await in componentDidMount to load in correct order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some troubles getting several functions loading in the correct order. From my code below, the first and second functions are to get the `companyID` `companyReference` and are not reliant on one and another.

The third function requires the `state` set by the first and second functions in order to perform the objective of getting the `companyName`.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const a = await this.companyIdParams();
    const b = await this.getCompanyReference();
    const c = await this.getCompanyName();
    a;
    b;
    c;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isCancelled = true;
  }

  companyIdParams = () => {
    const urlString = location.href;
    const company = urlString
      .split('/')
      .filter(Boolean)
      .pop();
    !this.isCancelled &&
      this.setState({
        companyID: company
      });
  };

  getCompanyReference = () => {
    const { firebase, authUser } = this.props;
    const uid = authUser.uid;
    const getUser = firebase.user(uid);
    getUser.onSnapshot(doc => {
      !this.isCancelled &&
        this.setState({
          companyReference: doc.data().companyReference
        });
    });
  };

  getCompanyName = () => {
    const { firebase } = this.props;
    const { companyID, companyReference } = this.state;
    const cid = companyID;
    if (companyReference.includes(cid)) {
      const getCompany = firebase.company(cid);
      getCompany.onSnapshot(doc => {
        !this.isCancelled &&
          this.setState({
            companyName: doc.data().companyName,
            loading: false
          });
      });
    } else if (cid !== null && !companyReference.includes(cid)) {
      navigate(ROUTES.INDEX);
    }
  };
```

How can I achieve this inside `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, so you can't determinate when the state is updated in a sync way.

1)
I recommend you don't use componentDidMount with async, because this method belongs to react lifecycle.

Instead you could do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = async () => {
  const a = await this.companyIdParams();
  const b = await this.getCompanyReference();
  const c = await this.getCompanyName();
}
```

2)

The companyIdParams method doesn't have a return, so you are waiting for nothing.
If you need to wait I would return a promise when setState is finished;

```
companyIdParams = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const urlString = location.href;
    const company = urlString
      .split('/')
      .filter(Boolean)
      .pop();
    !this.isCancelled &&
      this.setState({
        companyID: company
      }, () => { resolve() });
  });
};
```

The same for getCompanyReference:

```
getCompanyReference = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const { firebase, authUser } = this.props;
    const uid = authUser.uid;
    const getUser = firebase.user(uid);
    getUser.onSnapshot(doc => {
      !this.isCancelled &&
        this.setState({
          companyReference: doc.data().companyReference
        }, () => { resolve() });
    });
  });
};
```

3)

If you want to parallelize the promises, you could change the previous code to this:

```
const [a, b] = await Promise.all([
  await this.companyIdParams(),
  await this.getCompanyReference()
]);
```

4)

According to your code, the third promise is not a promise, so you could update (again ;) the above code:

```
const [a, b] = .....
const c = this.getCompanyName()
```

*EDIT: the bullet points aren't steps to follow*

Comment: I used Promise.all to parallelize calls :)

Comment: Thank you David, I am slightly confused by step 3 and 4. Aren't they repeating step 1 in `fetchData()`?

Comment: Ops, sorry for the confusion, there aren't steps. The points are like 4 ideas to apply to your code :P

Answer (score 2):

As the last api call is dependent on the response from the first 2 api calls, use a combination of `Promise.all` which when resolved will have the data to make the last dependent call

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    let [a, c] = await Promise.all([
        this.companyIdParams(),
        this.getCompanyReference()
    ]);

    const c = await this.getCompanyName();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Quick question as your example returns `Parsing error: await is a reserved word`. Where should `async` be placed to be allow `await`?

Comment: It isn't possible to do ```const c = await this.getCompanyName();``` because the closure doesn't have the async declaration